# jQuery, .load, javascript, (prevent scroll up), XMLHttpRequest, .innerHTML, CSS/JS NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When using this code no CSS/Javascript works (It just loads the HTML):

```
    function functionName(limit) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          var text = xhttp.responseText;
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", "?x=test&limit=" + limit, false);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

When using jQuery CSS/Javascript works, now the problem is that the page scrolls up when loading the content.

```
$('#content').load('?x=test&limit=" + limit);
```

What I want is a way to load an URL to a DIV, where CSS and Javascript works.
And like `.innerHTML` I want to load the content without scrolling to the top.

Hope for help, yesterday i googled for 6-8 hours, and im a google-fu guru =)

Comment: you know that your code is commented ? (not executed due to be within /* */)

Comment: @SamiGestblom If your answer (at your own post or at another) is not correct, please delete it and edit your post with new information, instead of creating another answer

Answer (score 0):

Still got the same problem!

When using XMLHttpRequest and .innerHTML it loads the HTML (without scrolling up to the start of the div). But no Javascript or CSS works...

And with this it loads Javascript and CSS when .load'ing. But it scrolls up to the start of the div.

$('#content').load("?x=test&limit=" + limit);

Comment: If your answer (at your own post or at another) is not correct, please delete it and edit your post with new information, instead of creating another answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    function functionName(limit) {

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

          var ele = document.createElement("script");
          ele.src = "js/some-js-ajax.js";
          document.body.appendChild(ele);   

          var text = xhttp.responseText;
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", "?x=test&limit=" + limit, false);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

When adding:
              var ele = document.createElement("script");
              ele.src = "js/some-js-ajax.js";
              document.body.appendChild(ele);

.innerHTML works with CSS and Javascript, but now it scrolls up to the start o fthe div again. Not staying in the scrolled place where you were before the functionName(limit) load ....